# Создать график и сохранить его в C# .NET Core, без отображения

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, диаграммы, oxyplot

Возникла необходимость на бэкенде нарисовать красивый график из данных, и успешно его отправить. Вьюшка не нужна, негде на бэкенде его отображать.

Неожиданно столкнулся с тем что как будто бы нет библиотек для этого. Для фронта очень много, тот же chart.js но для бэка как будто нет.

Есть библиотеки для рисования, типа ImageSharp, но графики с помощью них рисовать неудобно, придется писать обертку.

OxyPlot - в документации нет примеров на бэк, только на WPF, Xamarin, Silverlight и тд - в общем на платформы с вьюшками.

Есть какой то пакет в `NuGet OxyPlot.ImageSharp`, который вроде как и есть обертка над ImageSharp, но по нему просто нет документации.

```
var Plot = new PlotController();
var model = new PlotModel();
    
OxyPlot.ImageSharp.ImageRenderContext context = new ImageRenderContext(200,200,OxyColor.FromArgb(1,1,1,1));

context.SaveAsBmp();
```

Видно что контекст для рендера я получить могу.
И контекст этот умеет сохранять в файл.

Но как связать модель, контроллер и вообще наполнить график данными?

Поэтому вопрос немного общий - как сделать красивый график в консольном приложении .NetCore, и сохранить его в файл\стрим? Или, в случае если я копаю в правильном направлении - как работать с этой библиотекой?

Comment: Написал в гугле `c# create graph image`, получил [это](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.chart.saveimage), [это](https://github.com/image-charts/c-sharp), а если еще дальше искать, то даже есть [API генератор](https://quickchart.io/). А что касается `OxyPlot`, то также, гугл, запрос `c# oxyplot save image`, результат - [документация](https://oxyplot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/export/export-png.html).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ так я же написал что есть документация к oxyplot - но нет этого для консольного приложения на .netCore, там только wpf\xamarin и прочие варианты с вьюшкой.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если есть вариант как-то применить версию для wpf на .netcore то пожалуйста, напишите ответ